# What insect is this?

Tags: identification, insects

[image: Hand for size reference]

This bug appeared overnight in my backyard. I’m in southern Arizona USA. What is it?

Comment: Maybe biology.stackexchange is a better place for such questions. The site (and app) iNaturalist is also very good in identifying bugs and wild plants. BTW to me it seems just an exoskeleton of a grasshopper.

Answer (score 2):

It's a palo verde beetle (derobrachus hovorei). They show up during the summer months.